# ActionLink 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Building my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application and trying to implement the ability to disassociate a given ice cream from a menu.  Each has an integer identifier associated with it and on a page I display these mappings and provide a link by them to remove the ice cream from the menu.

I've got an `ActionLink` that looks like this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping", "IceCream", new { iceCreamId=item.IceCreamId, menuId=item.MenuId}, null)`

In my IceCreamController I've got an Action that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping(int iceCreamId, int menuId)
{
   ...
}
```

Did a little searching and believe I may need to modify the `routes` in the Global.asax.cs file's `RegisterRoutes` to handle these two parameters.  So I tried this like so:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RoutesCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   // I added this route in an attempt to handle the two parameters:
   routes.MapRoute(
      "RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping", // Route name
      "IceCream/RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping/{iceCreamId}/{menuId}", // URLwith parameters
      new
      {
         controller = "IceCream",
         action = "RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping",
         iceCreamId = UrlParameter.Optional,
         menuId = UrlParameter.Optional
      } 
   );

   // this was there by default
   routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   };
}
```

But this doesn't work - I get a "The resource cannot be found." error, 404.  Requested URL: /IceCream/RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping/1/10

1 is the Id of the IceCream and 10 is the menu's Id.

What I was expecting to happen was that the action `RemoveMenuIceCreamMapping` would get called, passing those two parameters, but I'm obviously not doing something right here and may just misunderstand how to accomplish what I want and be going about this the wrong way.  Any guidance would be most appreciated.

---

**Update**

So, one more thing I've learned, after reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281390/passing-parameters-from-textboxes-in-a-view-to-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc2), my `ActionLink` isn't triggering a POST so removing the `[HttpPost]` from the action seemed like the right thing to do.  And, in fact, as soon as I did that, the route was found and the action executed.

Comment: Have you tried without [HttpPost]?

Comment: @Sheen, yes - see my update to the question.  It worked w/out that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. html link which ActionLink really is just providing GET. If you want to POST, use form and submit button or ajax post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you problem is that the ActionLink uses an HTTP GET and you are only accepting HTTP POST.

You will probably need to change your view to issue an HTTP POST (e.g. with a regular HTML button inside a form) so that the verb that the browser sends matches with what you accept on the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hector.  So, I guess the question I have as a follow-up is "Any reason why I cannot/shouldn't just remove the [HttpPost] from the action?"

Comment: You can indeed remove the HttpPost from the action but it is recommended that "destructive actions" (like a delete) are handled through HTTP POST requests rather than HTTP GET. This prevents web crawlers visit them.